# Bash script to download JPG files from the website

Tags: linux, bash, curl, debian, download

I am a completely beginner in programming bash scripts (Linux, Debian), one of the use that I'd like to write is to make user able to download JPG or any other kind of graphic files from website he needs to, eg `./code1.sh www.bbc.com`. It doesn't interpret a website adress, an error shows: `there is no such a file or catalog like www.bbc.com`. Could you please write me what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
curl $1 | grep -o -e `$1.\{1,100\}\.jpg` > graph_list.txt
wget `cat graph_list.txt`
```

Comment: where is the curl program installed , change the PATH or add it to curl ,something like /usr/bin/curl

Comment: If you are passing the website in line after calling your script, try using $1 instead of `read mywebsite`. So just `curl $1 | grep blah`.
Also, are you on windows/linux/osx?  If linux or osx, what is the results of the command `which curl`

Comment: I can't find anywhere curl file. When I'm trying to install it by:    `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php5-curl`    it shows that my version of php5-curl is updated

Comment: @cashman04 nothing is shown in temrinal when i try `which curl`

Comment: `php5-curl` is an CURL module for php5 and not the command line `curl`. try `sudo apt-get install curl` see: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/curl

Comment: Are you sure the path to the images is correct? Also, your expansion is missing the dot before jpg e.g. `$1.\{1,100\}\.jpg` Also what @cashman04 said, you can drop the `read` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line with a simplified regular expression. This will get **all** the pictures (I'm not sure if I fully understand how you wanted to filter):

```
curl www.bbc.com | grep -o -e 'http[^"]*\.jpg' | xargs wget
```

Your code posted in the question cannot work because of the backticks (`` ` ``) you used to wrap your regular expression. Backticks trigger command substitution in Bash like you intentionally did in your last line, use quotes (`'`) to prevent tokenization and expansion or double quotes (`"`) to prevent tokenization instead.